# Should I use node.js for this?

Tags: node.js, web, panel, administration

My question is rather straightforward. I started developing quite a large project and realized that node.js COULD be a viable solution. Since I am still new to node and therefore not in the position to determine if it's the right thing for me, I decided to ask here.

The project: It's basically an administration solution for gameserver providers. It includes both a web administration panel as well as server components to control everything.

My doubts are if I should use node for the **panel**.

It will require life updating of data (where sockets could come in handy) and we plan on developing it as a "one-page" kind of app.
Having it node means it would be able to perform tasks asynchronously and on it's own (instead of, say, php and cronjobs)
It will be distributed. Making it node would make this easy. No dependencies besides node, and a simple "npm install".
It will have multiple people connecting to it and using it at the same time.

Will node be able to handle these multiple connections well? Performance wise, will it be a good choice?
Will node (and maybe [Derby](http://derbyjs.com//)) suffice to build a good web panel?
Am I right about any of the points I made, or did I miss something?

Thanks for the help!

Sincerely
-Antariano

Answer (score 0):

Well you did answer yourself for some of the questions. Thanks to the asynchronous tasks node can take quite a load of connections so it should handle your app. I don't know Derby, but [express](http://expressjs.com/) is also good for your task.

Also when one node server will be insufficient you can always deploy next one and just create some communication between them. Since node is lightweight it can do the job.

> Will node be able to handle these multiple connections well?

Yes.

> Performance wise, will it be a good choice?

Yes.

> Will node (and maybe Derby) suffice to build a good web panel?

Yes.

> Am I right about any of the points

You are right with all of them.

I think node will be sufficient for this job.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on the multiple node servers bit? How would that be done? Can you point me to some resources?

Comment: Here you have an article about [node multi core clustering](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/07/multicore_http_server_with_nodejs/).

Simply you just run multiple node servers and arrange some kind communication between them. Check out this node package [Cluster](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster)